# remove data labels automatically for new columns in pivot chart?

Tags: excel

I have a query that populates data set for a pivot table.  I want data labels to always be at none.  Whenever a new column shows up the data label comes back.  Anyway I can permanently remove them from the entire pivot chart?

this what it looks like when i remove data labels:
[image]

this what it looks like after refreshing data:
[image]

Can I stop data labels from showing up on new data?

Comment: its not code its the formatting of the chart.  if new columns come up data labels show.  i want them to never show.

Comment: updated with pics